# sql query for showing all rows of a table based on id with respect to another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have two tables.

- table: Schedule (`SID,ORID`)
- table:  ORC (`ORID,ORNAME`)

I want to show all `ORNAME`s whether they are allocated for particular SID or not.

Expected output:

```
   SID   OR1 OR2 OR3 OR4
    1     1             
    2             3
    3         2
```

Above, `SID` 1 contains `ORID` = 1, `SID` 2 contains `ORID` = 3, and `SID` 3 contains `ORID` = 2.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a pivot table

Comment: here is a [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31551/Pivot-two-or-more-columns-in-SQL-Server-2005) to get an idea

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a dynamic pivot that supports any number of possible values for `ORNAME`:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000) = STUFF(
(
SELECT  ',['+ORNAME+']'
FROM    ORC
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(3000) =
'
SELECT  pvt.SID,
        '+@cols+'
FROM    Schedule a
LEFT JOIN   
        ORC b ON a.ORID = b.ORID
PIVOT   (
    MAX(b.ORID) FOR b.ORNAME IN ('+@cols+')
) pvt
ORDER BY pvt.SID'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17d57/1/0)**